# Used a for loop to create a certain number of entry boxes but can only .get last value from last entrybox

Tags: python, list, loops, tkinter, python-3.3

I am new to Python and I'm trying to create a simple grade calculator with tkinter.
I used a loop to create a number of entryboxes as defined by the user-- for entering grades.
However, I don't know how to make the name of these entrybox values return all of the values in a list or something. (So far program only returns the last value entered in last entrybox).
I'm not sure how much information to include so I'm going to include a short description of what I'm trying to do:

1 Use loop to create X amount of entry boxes as defined by user

2 user enters grades

3 along with percentage worth of each grade

4 I then want to access each individual grade to multiply it to the percentage

5 then get the sum.

*what I have written so far does not include creating the entryboxes for the percentages because I have been focusing on just trying to get my program to return all the grades.

This is a portion of the code where I think the problem might be.

```
    self.abutton=tkinter.Button(self.Frame3,text="Average",command=self.getValues)
    self.abutton.pack(side='right')



def myClick(self):      
    self.x=self.myvalue.get()
    self.value=int(self.x)
    for n in range(self.value):
            self.Mylabel=Label(self.Frame2,text="Grade"+str(n+1)).place(x=10,y=30+(30*n))         
            self.Mygrade= Entry(self.Frame2, width=10)
            self.Mygrade.place(x=70,y=30+(30*n))







def getValues(self):
    self.test1 = ()
    nsum=0
    try:
        self.test1 = float(self.Mygrade.get())
    except ValueError:
        print("Error")
    else:
        print(self.test1)
```

I have also pasted the entire code here: http://pastebin.com/xC92BKeb

also, pardon any stray notes that I left for myself throughout the entire pastebin, I forgot to leave them out.

I would appreciate any information and/or criticisms about what I'm doing wrong and what I should be doing.

Comment: Forgot to include, that I'm using Python v3.3

Comment: Here's a (gentle) criticism: don't use place. Your GUIs will be easier to write and maintain, and will have better behavior when resized or run on different resolutions or with different fonts, if you use grid and/or pack. .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `myClick` method, `self.Mygrade` is overwritten with the last entry.

```
self.Mygrade= Entry(self.Frame2, width=10)
```

And in `getValues`, only one value is used.

```
self.test1 = float(self.Mygrade.get())
```

You should use some container data structure (like `list`) to keep references to `Entry` objects and use that list to calculate average.

---

```
def myClick(self):      
    x = self.myvalue.get()
    value = int(x)
    self.grades = [] # <---- to hold grade Entry objects.
    for n in range(self.value):
        Label(self.Frame2,text="Grade"+str(n+1)).place(x=10,y=30+(30*n))        
        grade = Entry(self.Frame2, width=10)
        grade.place(x=70,y=30+(30*n))
        self.grades.append(grade) # <---

def getValues(self):
    total = 0
    for grade in self.grades: # <--- iterate over entry objects.
        try:
            total += float(grade.get())
        except ValueError:
            print('Invalid value for grade: {}'.format(grade.get()))
    avg = total / len(self.grades)
    print('Average = {}'.format(avg))
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm still having trouble understanding the problem but I just tried your code and I'm just so happy that I have working code to compare with mine, I'm hoping to understand where I went wrong this way. Many thanks!